# Multiple sandbox items push to production

Tags: sandbox, change-set

I've made multiple changes in sandbox.. Custom fields, page layouts, modified picklists, workflows and apex buttons and reports.

I'm getting ready to push to production. Is it a good practice to select all custom fields, layouts reports etc into the change set? Or, is there a way select all the changes made by my user?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to select all changes made. You have to add them to the change set one by one. But it will check for missing dependencies and won't let you deploy if you've missed one.

There is a (non-free) third-party tool called [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) that lets you compare the schema of the sandbox and production org to view all of the changes you've made and select which ones you want to deploy. It's something to consider if you do deployments frequently enough to justify the cost.

Comment: Is there any harm in selecting all custom fields even if it includes some I didn't modify?

Comment: @Stavros So long as you're confident no one else has made any changes to those fields in production, there's no harm.

Comment: @Stavros - Additionally if you are deploying profiles you need to ensure that for the fields you did not touch that someone did not modify the profiles to grant access they should not have in production. Generally it is best to avoid adding items to a changes that was not modified just to get everything in there when you are unsure.